# How many queries are made to vote on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, voting

What happens when we vote?

1. Assert that user is not author of post on which he/she is voting
2. Delete existing vote (in case when we upvote, then downvote)
3. Vote (insert a vote record)
4. (decrement/)increment score of post on which voting is done
5. ## 4 requires to grab the weight of vote from vote_type table

Am I wrong or does it really take 5 queries to vote on SO?

Comment: There's even more stuff that goes into that, I'm sure.  What if the voter is out of votes? Also, all the complicated rep stuff (if it's a downvote, both users lose rep.  If it's an upvote, the post owner might be rep-capped, the post might be CW, etc).  And there's rate-limiting that comes into play when you vote too quickly.

Comment: i am sure so team is enough smart(or we can say expert ) to do in very less query at least less than 5

Comment: @jadarnel27 yes, you are right, so I was just wondering - one click makes so many queries...

Comment: @NullPointer sure, they are experts, but I think there are many queries anyway

Comment: If you would like a less-rigorous example, you could explore the OSQA software since it replicates a lot of the SE stuff. That should give you some idea.

Comment: It might take more. So what?

Comment: @Shog9 Nothing. I was doing voting system in my project and was curious if other implementations also have many stuff behind one click.

Comment: Well, there'll be as much "stuff" as is needed to fulfill the requirements. SO tends to have a lot of stuff going on, so there'll be checks that have to be made, and values updated (although I don't believe the value of the vote has to be queried for each vote, since that's consistent).

Comment: Re-opened because, while I don't think this is a particularly useful question, "not constructive" is utterly bogus. I could kinda see "Off topic" if I squint a bit.

Comment: Hey, let's be fair, I voted to close as too localized.

Comment: This was a question about SO, and there was an answer answering that question. That's it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It depends. On the scenario, and on how you measure it.

There are a few different behaviors attached to voting on SO: reputation gained or lost for the voter and votee, privileges gained/lost, friendly reminders about commenting or voting on questions more often... Restrictions on when, where, and who can vote... Real-time notifications for both post score and reputation changes...

And then there are things that don't happen right away, but are handled later on as-needed: cleanup for votes that shouldn't have been allowed but were, for fraudulent votes, etc... Recalculation of reputation when that gets out of sync with the actual voting... Badge awards...

I just up-voted this question. According to MiniProfiler, that resulted in something like 17 queries (most fairly trivial).

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer, can't up vote - not enough reputation yet! 17 queries.